# How to perform a shell redirection (command > output.txt) using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, mysql, windows, cmd

I wanted to backup a MySQL database using `ProcessBuilder` and the `>` character is not being interpreted as I expected. This is my code:

```
java.util.List<String> cmd = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
cmd.add("mysqldump");
cmd.add("-u");
cmd.add("root");
cmd.add("-p"+password);
cmd.add("DBx");
cmd.add(">");
cmd.add("DBbk.sql");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.directory(new File("."));
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The output is:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

Comment: Redirection is a _shell_ function.  You appear to be running `mysqldump` directly, so redirection will not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try (just displaying the significant portion of the solution):

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "your_command > DBbk.sql").start()
```

This way you're explicitly calling `cmd`. In Linux you could call `bash` or whatever shell you use.

Answer (score 7):

The process builder is executing the program directly, not executing it through a shell/command prompt. Therefore, you don't get any nice features of the shell like the `>` character for redirection. Sorry.